# Proof for primality based on exponents and primitive roots

Tags: number-theory, primitive-roots

I'm trying to prove the following statement:

Suppose $n > 1$. The number $n$ is prime if and only if there exists a number $b$ such that gcd$(b, n) = 1$ and $b^{n−1} ≡ 1$ (mod $n$) and $b^{(n−1)/d} \not ≡ 1$ (mod $n$) for all positive divisors $d$ of $n − 1$ with $d > 1$.

Here's what I have so far:

If $n$ is composite, by definition it has at least one positive divisor $d$ other than itself and 1. Since $\phi(n)$ counts the number of values $1 \ge x \ge n$ such that gcd$(x,n) = 1$ and we know that gcd$(d,n) \not = 1$ and gcd$(n,n) \not = 1$, $\phi(n)$ can be at most $n-2$. Thus, if $n$ is composite, $\phi(n) < n-1$. By the contrapositive, if $\phi(n) = n - 1$, $n$ is prime.

(We can say $=$ instead of $\ge$ because $\phi(n) \not = n$ for $n>1$.)

This result seems helpful but I can't connect the dots yet. The problem states that $exp_n(b) = n-1$, and I know that if $n$ is prime $\phi(n) = n-1$, making $b$ a primitive root. But this doesn't give me the proof I need yet. Can I get a hint in the right direction?

Comment: You know that if $n$ is not prime, then for _any_ $b$ we have $\exp_n(b)<n-1$, since $\exp_n(b)$ must divide $\phi(n)<n-1$. This is a full proof of implication going one way. Next you need to prove that if $n$ is indeed prime, then there is actually a $b$ of order $n-1$, but that's all of them except $1$ and $0$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the last sentence. Can you explain what you mean by a $b$ of order $n-1$?

Comment: What you call $\exp_n(b)$ is more commonly referred to as the _multiplicative order_ of $b$ modulo $n$. What I mean is, you need to prove the implication "$n$ is prime" $\implies$ "there is a $b$ such that $\exp_n(b)=n-1$",

Comment: If $n$ is prime, we know two things: $\phi(n) = n-1$ and $n$ must have a primitive root. Therefore if we call $b$ that primitive root, we know $exp_n(b) = \phi(n) = n - 1$. Is that the proof I need?

Comment: Yes, it is.${}$